# How do I open a .bat/.cmd/.exe file from pdf?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, cmd.exe

I have attached a hyperlink on word document (.docx) to open a .cmd or .exe file. On word, it works well, it opens the specified command file. But, when I convert the document to PDF and try to click on the link. It does not work anymore. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: What is the exact link and what does, “it does not work anymore,” mean? Is there an error or what behavior happens?

Comment: @Appleoddity nothing happens. no error or anything. The same hyperlink when clicked on word, opens the file (.bat) but does not on PDF even after I clicked on the hyperlink multiple times.

Comment: @Appleoddity also, when I click on Hyperlink in the PDF, it shows a security warning whether to allow or block from opening the link. I obviously click on Allow

Comment: What is the exact link?

Comment: Does the link in the PDF actually display the correct path? Also it sounds awful to even do this.

Comment: The link is to open an .exe file. Yes it displays exact path.

Comment: It might also matter the Portable Document Format Viewer. Even if you click on the _Allow_ Button, you should double-check the Settings related to this action inside the Viewer. Which one is it?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai It is Adobe Reader DC. I found the weird problem, to open external applications from PDF only works on full version of Adobe.

Comment: It is entirely possible that this is "by design". Allowing PDFs to run random executables could be a vector to trick people into running programs that give away administrator rights to random scripts on the internet. People may trust PDFs more than word documents.

Comment: This Issue is not limited _only_ to Portable Document Format Files. Generally, every Software Application _should_ avoid starting any kind of Executable Binary Files from within themselves. For instance, a Safe and Sane Web-Site is usually blocking even Character Strings such as `Cmd.Exe` from being H.T.T.P. POST-ed into them.

Comment: Pdfs block opening many extentions in links automatically and have for years.